# Qt press left click twice for context menu to disappear

Tags: qt, contextmenu

I'm trying to use a context menu from Qt when I press right click.

Here is what I've tried:

```
connect(mtreeView, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)),
        this, SLOT(showContextMenu(const QPoint&)));

Then
void MainTreeViewController::showContextMenu(const QPoint& pos)
{
    QPoint globalPos = mtreeView->mapToGlobal(pos);
    QMenu rightClickMenu;
    rightClickMenu.addAction(QString("Option"));
    rightClickMenu.exec(globalPos);
}
```

When I press right click, the menu appears. Then if I press left click outside of it nothing happens. I must press left click twice in order to make the menu disappear.

Why does that happen? Thanks!

Comment: Where do you call `menu.exec()`?

Comment: Your code seems fine. What OS and Qt version are you using?

Comment: Linux mint 17, Qt 5.0

Comment: On Linux Mint 17, Qt 4.8.6 this exact code works as expected. My guess - the problem is in Qt version. Try update, or downgrade it, if it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if `showContextMenu` is called twice for a single right click. You can verify by setting a breakpoint in `showContextMenu` and checking whether it is called twice.

Probably your signal slot connection is created twice, which can be the reason behind this. You can verify by setting a breakpoint to the line where signal slot connection is made.